# tic tac toe 4x4 python

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

i'm working in a tic tac toe 4x4 with minmax , the algorythm runs, but does nothing, i think that the problem is in "def ganador" or "def juega_humano" reading the inputs, i would greatly appreciate any help, thanks

PD: sorry for my tarzan english

```
#the lines for win
def ganador(tablero):
  lineas = [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11], [12,13,14,15], [0,4,8,12], [1,5,9,13], [2,6,10,14], [3,7,11,15], [0,5,10,15], [3,6,9,12]]
  ganador = 0
  for linea in lineas:
      if tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[1]] and tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[2]] and tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[3]] and tablero[linea[0]] != 0:
          ganador = tablero[linea[0]]
   return ganador

def ver_tablero(tablero):
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        if tablero[i*4+j] == MAX:
            print 'X',
        elif tablero[i*4+j] == MIN:
            print 'O',
        else:
            print '.',

    print ''
def juega_humano(tablero):
  ok=False
  while not ok:
    casilla = input ("Casilla?")
    # 0 to exit, 1-16 for cells defined with "range" in another place
    if str(casilla) in '012345678910111213141516' and (len(str(casilla))<= 2)   and tablero[casilla-1] == 0:
        if casilla == 0:
            sys.exit(0)
        tablero[casilla-1]=MIN
        ok=True
  return tablero
def juega_ordenador(tablero):
  global jugada_maquina
  punt = minimax(tablero[:], MAX)
  tablero[jugada_maquina] = MAX
  return tablero
if __name__ == "__main__":
  print 'Introduce casilla o 0 para terminar'
  tablero = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  while (True):
    ver_tablero(tablero)
    tablero = juega_humano(tablero)
    if game_over(tablero):
        break
    tablero = juega_ordenador(tablero)
    if game_over(tablero):
        break
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Firstly, it would be great if you could [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32899827/edit) your question to properly indent your code. Especially in python, it's very difficult to tell if the error is indent related.

Comment: The first problem I can see is that your functions aren't indented. After each `def` statement, you should have indentation. I can't post indentation as a comment, so I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I can see is that your functions aren't indented. After each def statement, you should have indentation. For example, this is wrong:

```
def ganador(tablero):
lineas = [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11], [12,13,14,15], [0,4,8,12], [1,5,9,13], [2,6,10,14], [3,7,11,15], [0,5,10,15], [3,6,9,12]]
ganador = 0
for linea in lineas:
    if tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[1]] and tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[2]] and tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[3]] and tablero[linea[0]] != 0:
        ganador = tablero[linea[0]]

return ganador
```

This would be correct:

```
def ganador(tablero):
    lineas = [[0,1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,9,10,11], [12,13,14,15], [0,4,8,12], [1,5,9,13], [2,6,10,14], [3,7,11,15], [0,5,10,15], [3,6,9,12]]
    ganador = 0
    for linea in lineas:
        if tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[1]] and tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[2]] and tablero[linea[0]] == tablero[linea[3]] and tablero[linea[0]] != 0:
            ganador = tablero[linea[0]]

    return ganador
```

Do that for your whole code, and see if that solves your problem. If not, see if you can narrow it down a little: the amount of code you just posted is quite large (two full screens), and most people aren't going to want to scroll through the entire thing. If you can narrow it down to "okay, this is the function that's going wrong", then more people will be likely to help you find a solution.

(**NOTE:** When I say "This would be correct", I only mean with regard to indentation. I haven't actually looked at your program's logic; there could still be a bug in your `ganador` function, for all I know.)

**EDIT:** Found one problem in your logic. This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
if str(casilla) in '012345678910111213141516' and # ... rest of line left out
```

If `casilla` is 91, this will be true, because the string "91" can be found in that string you're checking against. If you want to check that `casilla` *only* contains valid input, you should check it against a list of valid strings, like this:

```
if str(casilla) in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15'] and # ... rest of line left out
```

(Notice that I left out '16': if you accept '16' as valid input, you're going to have an IndexError at some point.)

Although there's a much better way to do this check. Why bother with converting it to a string, when you really just want to know if it's between 0 and 15? Just do this:

```
if 0 <= casilla <= 15 and # ... rest of line left out
```

I may give you more help later on, but that's enough for now. Indent your functions properly, and see if your problem goes away. If it doesn't, try to narrow it down, then post a new question with the narrowed-down code.

(Hint for narrowing it down: stick `print` statements all over the place, printing out the values that you're getting at different places in your code, and see if they look right or wrong to you. A good debugger is even better, but if you don't have a debugger, `print` statements can take you a long way.)

Comment: Update: I just saw your comment about 0 to exit, and 1-16 for valid cells, and that you subtract 1 from the input before using it as an index. So ignore my comment about how accepting '16' as input would give you an IndexError later on; that's not actually true in your case, and you should be checking `0 <= casilla <= 16`.